# Moving from one git branch to another and applying only my changes

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I've forked a project (from branch A), and it seems that for some reason it was continued in another branch(B).

I tried to merge my fork (M) with the new branch (B), but that has resulted a lot of conflicts. The conflicts are because the new branch (B) has forked older branch (O) and part of the changes of A were not committed to B.

Now I would like all my changes (in branch M) to be merged with the new branch B with no conflicts, canceling all changes made by A to the origin O in my fork M.

[image]

what I want is in red. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't follow what is happening.  Can you clarify your question, possibly with a branch diagram?

Comment: I added a graph, hope you understand, I want to "fork" B, with the changes I made to the fork of A.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you've made commit M on top of commits O and A but now want to apply only that last commit on top of B, which also has O in its graph but is in a different branch to A and (currently) M. In which case, have you looked into "cherry picking"? You will probably still have to resolve some conflicts.

Comment: So are you saying you want all commits occurring _after_ commit `A` in the `M` branch to be applied to the `B` branch?

Comment: I made changes to a branch that had been forked from A. And now I want to move to branch B, undoing all A changes and applying all B changes.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to cherry-pick the range of commits in the `M` branch which occurred after the `A` commit, from the `B` branch:

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick 2an38xma..f8s3kow2
```

Here `2an38xma` is the SHA-1 hash, or unique identifier, of the `A` commit in the `M` branch.  You can find this commit hash by typing `git log` from the `A` branch and scrolling down until you find the `A` commit.  The range used in `git cherry-pick` says to apply one-by-one the commits *after* the `A` commit until the final commit `f8s3kow2` in the `M` branch.

Keep in mind that you may get merge conflicts with each commit.

Comment: There is a problem:
The forked branch (M) has been merging several times with A.
So this might create a lot of problems.
What might help is that, only one user (me) committed in the forked branch(M).

Comment: The general solution doesn't change.  Just identify the commits you want and cherry pick them.  By the way, your diagram is inadequate because it doesn't show the multiple merges.

Comment: We are talking about hundreds of changes... Is there any option to cherry-pick all my commits?

Comment: Can you express those hundreds of commits in the form of a few ranges?

Answer (score 1):

First make a copy of the original `M` branch with `git branch M.old M` so that you trivially can start over if things end up not like you want it.

Then you can rebase your M branch to start from B with

```
git rebase --onto B A M
```

This should give you exactly the red M branch in your drawing.

`A` here marks the start (not including) from where you want to consider changes and `M` the endpoint (including), which will be updated to the rebase result.